# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What kind of impact have parental quarrels on children?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/what-kind-of-impact-have-parental-quarrels-on-children)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to handle disclosing a parent's suicide to friends and their parents](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/how-to-handle-disclosing-a-parents-suicide-to-friends-and-their-parents)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do we deal with my toddler son's "angry behavior"?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/how-do-we-deal-with-my-toddler-sons-angry-behavior)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [At what age does an infant start recognizing people?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/at-what-age-does-an-infant-start-recognizing-people)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How do you prepare a pre-schooler for potentially permanent separation from a close friend?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9056/how-do-you-prepare-a-pre-schooler-for-potentially-permanent-separation-from-a-cl)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can a 17-month old really appreciate humour/irony?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8874/can-a-17-month-old-really-appreciate-humour-irony)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why are there so many snaps on infant clothes?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9125/why-are-there-so-many-snaps-on-infant-clothes)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Do I need to put cloth diapers through two wash cycles?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/do-i-need-to-put-cloth-diapers-through-two-wash-cycles)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [why does my daughter wake up in pain clawing at herself?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/why-does-my-daughter-wake-up-in-pain-clawing-at-herself)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What are some alternatives to bouncing on an exercise ball?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8948/what-are-some-alternatives-to-bouncing-on-an-exercise-ball)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 4):

I think over-all, this site keeps it simple.  So many parenting sites have so many "answers" that are really just, "yeah me too!"  It really is so much easier to ask a question and get a real answer here.  Then when looking at questions that were already asked, you aren't scrolling through all those non answers either.  That alone makes a HUGE difference to me.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Sorry, I have to rant just a little here...</sub>

One piece of completely unrelated feedback is that **the text box with the instructions takes up way too much of my screen space!**  If I open the review queue on my 1024*600 netbook then the area for the actual posts is approx. **76 pixels** (seventy-six!) high...

I realize that web developers like the SE staff are probably using triple 40" monitors but many ordinary users have crappy old machines. Yeah, I can just work through the review queue from my 26" desktop **at work** - but my employer might not appreciate that. Even on my work computer's giant 1680*1050 screen, the area for the actual posts is still less than half of the screen, around 500px.

*Please* find a way to make those instructions take up less space. This isn't fun. Thanks for listening.

**Update:**

After several reviews, I notice a small link that solves it for me ... but that's very well hidden (even in plain sight):
[image]
Am I just too blind to use a computer, or do other people also experience this?

Comment: I thought it defaulted to the smaller size, and it only showed the expanded instructions when you click (more)... but I may have that wrong.

Comment: Hrmm .. when you think about it, there's no reason why the system should show you those instructions more than once, or once you say 'yeah, okay, I got it'. Might take a little bit but I'll check into it.

Comment: @Beofett the text box was open when I visited the queue. I just visited again and now it was closed but I don't know whether the system remembers that I closed it because that was on a different computer.

Comment: @TimPost thanks for looking into it :-)

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun I totally agree (about the going blind)!!! I have my default browser zoom set at greater than 100% :)

Comment: You do realised you answered a question with a question? :)